# ASP.Net web api2 - not working when the api returns a boolean

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am using Postman to test an ASP.Net web api 2 application that I created using I created using VS 2017.

It uses ADO.Net to call stored procedures. I tested the stored procedures and they work fine. I created a console app to test the methods and they work fine.

[image]

The URL that returns a model object works fine.
http://localhost:56224/api/profileandblog/getactiveuser/2020-03-03/DancinDan/32.211.50.62/1

[image]

The URL that returns a boolean does not. I get Error - 404.0 - Not Found
http://localhost:56224/api/profileandblog/validatelogin/2020-03-03/DancinDan/Morewealth1/32.211.50.62

[image]

Here is the dataaccesslayer.cs in my Models folder:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using GbngWebApi2.ADO_Utilities;

namespace GbngWebApi2.Models
{
    public class DataAccessLayer
    {
    DatabaseFunctions dbFunc = new DatabaseFunctions();

    public bool ValidateLogin(DateTime currentDateTime, string userName, string userPassword, string ipAddress)
    {
        bool returnedStatus = false;

        try
        {
            dbFunc.OpenDB();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.ValidateLogin", dbFunc.objConn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_CurrentDateTime", currentDateTime);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_UserName", userName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_UserPassword", userPassword);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_IpAddress", ipAddress);

            // Set the OUT parameter.
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@a_PasswordStatusSwitchOut", SqlDbType.Bit);
            cmd.Parameters["@a_PasswordStatusSwitchOut"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Get the value from the OUT parameter.
            // Cast to Boolean.
            returnedStatus = (bool)cmd.Parameters["@a_PasswordStatusSwitchOut"].Value;

            return returnedStatus;
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlex)
        {
            throw sqlex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            dbFunc.CloseDB();
        }
    }

    public User GetActiveUser(DateTime currentDateTime, string userName, string ipAddress, int userId)
    {
        User user = new User();

        SqlDataReader userDataReader = null;

        try
        {
             dbFunc.OpenDB();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetActiveUser", dbFunc.objConn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_CurrentDateTime", currentDateTime);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_UserName", userName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_IpAddress", ipAddress);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_UserId", userId);

            userDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (userDataReader.Read())
            {
                user.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(userDataReader["UserId"]);
                user.UserName = userDataReader["UserName"].ToString();                     
                user.ActiveSwitch = Convert.ToInt32(userDataReader["ActiveSwitch"]);
                user.ApiAccessSwitch = Convert.ToInt32(userDataReader["ApiAccessSwitch"]);
                user.AdminSwitch = Convert.ToInt32(userDataReader["AdminSwitch"]);
                user.BlogAuthorSwitch = Convert.ToInt32(userDataReader["BlogAuthorSwitch"]);
                user.BlogUserName = userDataReader["BlogUserName"].ToString();
                user.IpAddress = userDataReader["IpAddress"].ToString();
                user.IpAddressUsedForRegisteringCount = Convert.ToInt32(userDataReader["IpAddressUsedForRegisteringCount"]);
                user.LoginCount = Convert.ToInt32(userDataReader["LoginCount"]);
                user.ModifiedCount = Convert.ToInt32(userDataReader["ModifiedCount"]);
                user.SuggestionCount = Convert.ToInt32(userDataReader["SuggestionCount"]);
                user.SelectedForPublicViewSwitch = Convert.ToInt32(userDataReader["SelectedForPublicViewSwitch"]);
                user.ModifiedDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(userDataReader["ModifiedDateTime"]);                    
                user.CreatedDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(userDataReader["CreatedDateTime"]);
            }

            return user;
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlex)
        {
            throw sqlex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (userDataReader != null)
            {
                userDataReader.Close();
            }

            dbFunc.CloseDB();
        }
    }     
}
}
```

Here is the WebApi2Controller:

```
    using System;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using GbngWebApi2.Models;

    namespace GbngWebApi2.Controllers
    {
       [RoutePrefix("api/profileandblog")]
       public class WebApi2Controller : ApiController
       {
         DataAccessLayer dataaccesslayer = new DataAccessLayer();

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("validatelogin/{currentDateTime}/{userName}/{userPassword}/{ipAddress}")]
    public bool ValidateLogin(DateTime currentDateTime, string userName, string userPassword, string ipAddress)
    {
        try
        {
            // Returns a boolean indicator of success or failure.
            return dataaccesslayer.ValidateLogin(currentDateTime, userName, userPassword, ipAddress);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getactiveuser/{currentDateTime}/{userName}/{ipAddress}/{userId}")]
    public User GetActiveUser(DateTime currentDateTime, string userName, string ipAddress, int userId)
    {
        try
        {
            // Returns the active "user" from the database.
            return dataaccesslayer.GetActiveUser(currentDateTime, userName, ipAddress, userId);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }     
}
 }
```

Comment: It is because the called URL has a `.` file extension `/32.211.50.62` and the route handler thinks you are looking for a file which does not exists and thus throws not found

Comment: They both have the ip address. But 1 has a /1 following it. (the one that works).

Comment: right that one will work because if does not end with a anything that looks like a file extension

Comment: Add a slash at the end and it will work `/32.211.50.62/`

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks. How do I give you credit?

Comment: no worries. Glad to help

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Nkosi: Add a slash at the end and it will work /32.211.50.62/